# How to search for people not in any groups

Tags: search-builder, searchkit

I am trying to find people who are not in any groups (both regular and smartgroups)
If I use Search Builder, search for contacts where GROUP is empty or is null it returns people who have no regular groups but who are in smartgroups

If I use Search Kit there is no obvious way to do the search

Would love some ideas as to how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Custom search include/exclude?
Thats normally the way I would try to find everyone who is not in a group/segment.

Comment: Yes, but I think you will have to use Search Builder to find everyone in any group (not empty), create a new group from them and then use include/exclude search to find the complement of that group (those not in any group)

Comment: The custom search with excluding all the groups supposed to be fine. It lists me only those contacts that are not in groups.